# BAT or VBS to edit existing xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file, vbscript

I was after some code for either a BAT or VBS to add a line into an existing XML file…

Example of existing XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Feature>
    <Feature #1001>
    <Feature #22002>
<Feature>
```

Example of where I am wanting to insert say “Feature #0000” to look like below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Feature>
    <Feature #0000>
    <Feature #1001>
    <Feature #22002>
<Feature>
```

The existing xml file have varying content so I was thinking something that looks for the first `“<Feature>”` then inserts directly the line after regardless what follows after.

Any idea much appreciated!

Comment: This is not even a valid `xml` file...

Comment: If you're dealing with valid XML, VBS has API specifically for handling XML ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328907/add-child-entry-to-a-specific-node-in-xml-file-in-vbscipt)) and I don't think BAT has anything similar..

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion vbs is better as you can easily manager spaces , linebreaks, special characters... in Bat it's gonna be a little bit difficult to know what you are doing (like adding spaces), also vbs has some features for searching strings, replacing, selecting... Bat as far as i know doesn't have these ones.
**NOTE :** a simple problem using vbs is putting the `"`  character but actually using
  `chr(34) & "your text" & chr(34)` can do the job , hope this help